# How to style the browser's autocomplete dropdown box?

Tags: html, css, autocomplete

[image: http://dns.themeister.se/styleable.png]

As you see, the whitebox are my often used usernames.

The autocompletion box has a white background. Is it possible to change it to whatever I want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling autocomplete dropdowns in browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313543/styling-autocomplete-dropdowns-in-browsers)

Comment: Are you referring to the browsers native auto complete (my guess)?  Or are you using a plugin?

Comment: @Jared I use the browsers native auto complete.

Comment: @JoakimMelin then you are out of luck here.  You will have to use a plugin and disable the default autocomplete.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to modify the browsers' native functionality.

Comment: this is assuming that he is using a plugin.  The question and the image given point more towards the OP referring to the built in functionality of the browser which ISN'T something you can apply CSS to.

Comment: Agreed, I updated my post, I misunderstood him, at first. Ty.

Comment: Is anyone aware of ANY scripts or plugins out there that cane be used to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One can't possibly style the autocomplete dropdown since ***it's not in the DOM***.