# css transform property on textbox

Tags: html, css, textbox, transform

I hosted my site, and have used css3 transforms to rotate the content of one of the pages. You can have a look [here](http://www.tauqirpervez.com/contact/).
If I open the page in Firefox, when I click on any of the textboxes, the auto complete suggestions show as if the textbox was not rotated, and it makes the site look bad.
I have applied the following transform on the container div:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(355deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(355deg);
-o-transform: rotate(355deg);
```

The snapshot is as shown below.
[image: Image snapshot]
Can anyone please suggest how I can fix it? Thanks in advance. :)

PS: Chrome doesn't give me autocomplete for some reason, tried in multiple systems.

EDITED:

I'm using asp textboxes, so I can use the `autocompletetype="disabled"` to turn off autocomplete, but I was wondering if there was a way to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you fix it with autocomplete off?

```
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" />
```

**Edit:** 
Seems to be impossible otherwise: [How to style the browser's autocomplete dropdown box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595824/how-to-style-the-browsers-autocomplete-dropdown-box)

Comment: it is an asp textbox, so I can use autocompletetype="disabled", however I was wondering if there was any way to show the suggestion correctly.. probably should have mentioned that in the question..

Comment: According to my searches, there is no way to style browsers autocomplete. You can disable it and use your own javascript autocomplete, but that won't serve any purpose for you form since you can not get the data saved in the browser..