# can you access html input predictions?

Tags: html, css, input

if a viewer has already used a specific input tag previously, it remembers what they have searched, and, if they have searched that same sequential pattern, a pop up appears with their most common searches (at least for me in chrome it does).

**Can one change the styling for those pop-ups and/or disable them? If so, how?**

Comment: Mostly answered by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595824/how-to-style-the-browsers-autocomplete-dropdown-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't restyle the browser's native autocomplete ([How to style the browser's autocomplete dropdown box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595824/how-to-style-the-browsers-autocomplete-dropdown-box)).  However, it is possible to disable that dropdown by setting `autocomplete="off"` on the input element ([How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)).