# Style Autofill or Autocomplete Default Browser Dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, autofill

Is there some type of css prefix, plugin, javascript, or jquery that allows you to style the default browser autocomplete/autofill **dropdown**. Not for a search field... but for `<input type="email">`

I already use `input:-webkit-autofill`, `input:-webkit-autofill:hover`, and `input:-webkit-autofill:first-line` to change the appearence of the yellow background, the font-family, color, etc. (in Chrome)

Now I'm trying to override the default look of the **dropdown** - which is generated by your browser.

1. I'm trying to customize the appearence, text color, :hover color, font, etc. for all Username/Email autofill dropdowns.
2. I do not want to specify a data-list, or have any prefdefined variables...
3. I do not want to turn `autocomplete="off"`

I use **dropkick.js** to customize all of my `<select>` dropdowns - and change them into `<ul>` elements.

I am wondering if something like this exists for customizing all the other autofill or autocomplete dropdowns in a similar way.

**Is this even possible?**

[image: Concept]

Answer (score 2):

I had this identical question, unfortunately [everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595824/how-to-style-the-browsers-autocomplete-dropdown-box) [I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313543/styling-autocomplete-dropdowns-in-browsers) says that this can't be done in any sort of "native" way. The primary suggestion that most give is setting auto-complete to off and then building & styling [your](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element) [own](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), which in most instances is probably more work then it's worth.