# How to style Google search 'Autocomplete' results

Tags: javascript, css, google-search-api

I would like to know how can I style the google search 'Autocomplate' results?
My question is specific to the options that show in 'autocomplete' box and not the results ($('.gsc-table-result')).

I have tried to debug it in the firebug, but i am not able to find the html elements which are shown in the autocomplete result.

Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Prakhar

PS : I understand how styling autocomplete works. My question is specific to Google search API autocomplate results and I am unable to apply it to the autocomplete results from this specific api because I am unable to get the element class/id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style autocomplete dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308574/how-to-style-autocomplete-dropdown-list)

Comment: No. Its specific to the style for autocomplete from google search api. I understand how styling works, but unable to apply it to the autocomplete results from this specific api as I am unable to get the element class/id

Comment: If you want to style the suggestion box that popups upon response then you can follow [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete) guide you can style as you like but you should note that your styled popup should display the  "powered by google" with its logo , removing that would be a violation of their T&C