# How to remove border and background of input in ms edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

It appears when dropdown with `suggestion texts` opens the input is hovered.
Setting focus, active, hover styles doesn't help. It looks like it's out of DOM.
[image]
How can I remove the border and the background of an input text in Edge?

**UPDATE**

If there is no css solution, can anybody answer me with a link to how-it-works-article and/or provide me a javascript workaround (I want it to be like in google.com search input).

Comment: Could you share yous HTML and CSS snippets?

Comment: please provide fiddle or html code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the answers given to [this similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308574/how-to-style-autocomplete-dropdown-list), and as you suspected yourself, the autocomplete list that appears beneath the textbox is out of the DOM and so cannot be targeted by CSS.

From my experimenting on codepen it appears that Edge is overlaying a semi-transparent element over the textbox (matched in both height and width), rather than the styling being applied to the textbox itself.

[My first demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvWEWq) shows what happens with the styling when autocomplete is turned off. You will see that by chaining the `:hover` and `:focus` pseudo-classes I can create a different style when hovering over a textbox that is already in focus (blue when in focus, red when hovering over the same textbox when it is in focus).

This is worth noting when looking at [my second demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqvEZx) (in Edge, obviously) which has autocomplete turned on. When you click into the textbox the background colour is red (as is expected - I am hovering over a textbox that is in focus). However, move your mouse slightly and the background changes to blue, indicating that the textbox is active but is no longer being hovered over. This isn't correct - we're still hovering over it.

This could be a quirk with Edge, or a bug with how the browser handles autocomplete. It could be worth raising with Microsoft - there doesn't appear to be anything listed regarding this on their [issue tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/?page=1&q=autocomplete).

One of the answers given in the first link I provided suggests using [jQueryUI's implementation of autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). It's a bit of a faff when the browser should do it by default, but you will be able to target the styling of the autocomplete list and, in theory, avoid the issue you are having.

Comment: There were no answers that fully satisfy me. But I want to reward this one, because it tries to understand the problem and suggests variant of solving my problem without giving up dropdown.

Comment: @g1un - I appreciate it, though it's a shame we couldn't find a better solution. I think I will log the issue with Microsoft anyway, just to get their take on it. If they do fix it it will be one less browser quirk to worry about

Comment: Is there some link to the issue?

Comment: @DanielRuf - I never got round to logging it, but the issue I demonstrated in my codepen seems to be working as expected in Edge now.

Comment: Well so far we could not solve it with CSS and there seems to be no solution so far.

Comment: Interestingly, while it was working on my work laptop it doesn't appear to be behaving on my desktop at home...

Comment: Apparently once I save login in Google Chrome and it starts using autofill - the behaviour is exactly the same as in Edge

Answer (score 8):

You have to add `autocomplete="off"` in your `input` field

`<input type="text" placeholder="Type here" autocomplete="off">`

**And**

If it is a dynamic element or you can't add this in your `input` then you can do this with a simple script

`$('input').attr('autocomplete','off');`

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) can be useful for you

Answer (score 5):

Better turn off the `autocomplete`

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type here" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't resolve it in Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Just add `outline: none;` in ur css and it should do the trick!

**CSS**:

```
input { 
   outline: none;
}
```

or

**HTML**:

```
<input style="outline: none;" type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
```

Comment: this was it at least for me

Comment: keep in mind that the outline is important for people navigating by keyboard because if you remove it they won't know which element is focused - make sure you add styling for the `:focus` selector to make sure you don't confide anybody

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, I have no access to IE right now, but in other browsers some default behaviours can be updated using some CSS. Hope it can help you:

```
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
```