# Are there any ways to style HTML5 input element dropdown

Tags: html, css

HTML5 email input element shows a list of email address during typing. Is there a way to style it. I mean are there any CSS selectores.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling autocomplete dropdowns in browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313543/styling-autocomplete-dropdowns-in-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No**.

The list of email addresses you are seeing has to be a part of your browsers auto-complete functionalities. I just tried an HTML 5 email input element with recent Chrome and IE 10 versions, but no list was displayed. There is no way to edit these with CSS selectors.

However, if you create your own auto-complete / dropdown list controls using JavaScript, you are free to use any CSS style attributes such as colors, paddings and margins.